# Twilio iOS SDK fails to call with error code 31000

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, twilio

I am working on Twilio iOS SDK 1.2. **Each time I am able to get token successfully but facing random calling issue**. Sometimes call happens smoothly and sometimes it gives an error

> 2016-09-08 19:40:08.910 ProjectName[10762:529423] PJSIP(2): tsx0x1481812a8  Failed to send Request msg INVITE/cseq=11322 (tdta0x148189400)! err=70009 (Operation timed out (PJ_ETIMEDOUT))
>   2016-09-08 19:40:08.921 ProjectName[10762:529290] Twilio Services Error
>   2016-09-08 19:40:09.914 ProjectName[10762:529423] 19:40:09.914 ERROR:     [0x108320000] AVAudioSessionUtilities.h:111: GetProperty: AudioSessionGetProperty ('cilt') failed with error: '!siz'

one more error log in details

> 2016-09-21 16:01:33.838 ProjectName[678:65030] PJSIP(2): tsx0x13ea514a8  Failed to send Request msg INVITE/cseq=1739 (tdta0x13ea55200)! err=70009 (Operation timed out (PJ_ETIMEDOUT))
>    2016-09-21 16:01:33.848 ProjectName[678:64877] didFailWithError Error Domain=TwilioServicesErrorDomain Code=31000 "Twilio Services Error" UserInfo=0x17107dc40 {NSLocalizedDescription=Twilio Services Error} disctription = Twilio Services Error
>    2016-09-21 16:01:34.841 ProjectName[678:65030] 16:01:34.841 ERROR:     [0x104a00000] AVAudioSessionUtilities.h:111: GetProperty: AudioSessionGetProperty ('cilt') failed with error: '!siz'
>    2016-09-21 16:01:34.841 ProjectName[678:65030] 16:01:34.841 ERROR:     [0x104a00000] AVAudioSessionUtilities.h:124: GetProperty_DefaultToZero: AudioSessionGetProperty ('cilt') failed with error: '!siz'

For your reference attaching objective C code.

```
- (void)getTokenSuccessful:(NSDictionary *)message
```

{

```
NSString *receiverNumber = [message objectForKey:@"receiverNumber"];
NSString *sourceNumber = [message objectForKey:@"sourceNumber"];
NSString *twilioToken = [message objectForKey:@"twilioToken"];

_phone = [[TCDevice alloc] initWithCapabilityToken:twilioToken
                                              delegate:self];

NSDictionary *dictParams;
[UIDevice currentDevice].proximityMonitoringEnabled = YES;
dictParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:receiverNumber, @"Target", sourceNumber, @"Source", nil];

self.connectionObj = [self.phone connect:dictParams delegate:self];
[self addCallStartedView];
```

}

where self.connectionObj is object of class TCConnection. I have tried with creating new connection object each time before asking for token.

```
-(void)startCallForTourId:(NSString*)tourId andReceiverId:(NSString*)reciverId

{
[self.connectionObj disconnect];
[self.phone disconnectAll];

self.phone = nil;
self.connectionObj = nil;

_connectionObj = [[TCConnection alloc] init];
_phone = [[TCDevice alloc] init];

TwilioProxy *twilioProxy = [[TwilioProxy alloc] init];
twilioProxy.delegate = self;    
[twilioProxy getTokenForTourId:tourId andReceiverId:reciverId];
}
```

Checked with setting different AVAudioSession's categories like AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient etc. But this doesn't make any difference.

Please let me know if I am missing something, Any help is appreciated.